# consumer.How to specify partition to read? [kafka]

Tags: java, apache-kafka, partition, consumer

I am learning Kafka and I want to know how to specify then partition when I consume messages from a topic.

I have found several pictures like this:

[image]

It means that a consumer can consume messages from several partitions but a partition can only be read by a single consumer (within a consumer group).

Also, I have read several examples for consumer and they look like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("group.id", "consumer-tutorial");
props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
```

and:

Subscribe:

```
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(“foo”, “bar”));
```

Poll

```
 try {
      while (running) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
            System.out.println(record.offset() + ": " + record.value());
      }
 } finally {
      consumer.close();
 }
```

How does this work? From which partition will I read messages?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways to tell what topic/partitions you want to consume: [KafkaConsumer#assign()](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign(java.util.Collection)) (you specify the partition you want and the offset where you begin) and `subscribe` (you join a consumer group, and partition/offset will be dynamically assigned by group coordinator depending of consumers in the same consumer group, and may change during runtime)

In both case, you need to `poll` to receive data.

See https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html, especially paragraphs `Consumer Groups and Topic Subscriptions` and  `Manual Partition Assignment`

Comment: **you specify the partition you want and the offset where you begin** where do I specify offset ?

Comment: public void seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)