# Kafka multiple consumer from different partitions

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have 4 partitions and 4 consumers(A,B,C,D for example).
How to configure which consumer will read from which partition using consumer groups.
I am using Kafka with Spring boot.

Comment: please provide complete information. Whether consumer are in same consumer group? Have you read about kafka assigner classes?

Comment: Consumers are divided into 2 groups each having one consumer.

Comment: So you want to ensure that the four consumers each get a different partition? Or you want each specific consumer to get a specific pre-determined partition?

Comment: Just see if below thread can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492707/consumer-how-to-specify-partition-to-read-kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, kafka will automatically assign the partitions; if you have 4 consumers in the same group, they will eventually get one partition each. There are properties to configure kafka so it won't immediately do the allocation while you bring up your consumers.

You can also assign the partitions yourself.

Using

```
public ContainerProperties(TopicPartitionInitialOffset... topicPartitions)
```

if you are building the container yourself, or

```
@KafkaListener(id = "baz", topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = "${topic}",
            partitions = "${partition}"))
```

if you are using `@KafkaListener`.