# How to bind message types to Kafka consumers on a single consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a producer `producer` who wants to send `some_persistent_message` to `dbConsumer` and `some_Notification_message` to `notificationConsumer`

`Producer1` is sending the message with keys

```
db_key: some_persistent_message

notify_key:some_Notifiction_message
```

On the consumer side, I have a consumer group `App1_group` with the two consumers `dbConsumer` and `notificationConsumer`

[image]

At this point in time, my `dbConsumer` is always getting messages of `some_Notification_message` because of my consumer ending up owning a specific partition which is always getting `notify_key:some_Notifiction_message`

Is it possible to send `some_persistent_message` to `dbConsumer`
and `some_Notification_message` to `notification_consumer`?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492707/consumer-how-to-specify-partition-to-read-kafka helping?

Comment: are you specific about that partitions? or consumers?

Comment: Why not use different topics and different consumer groups? One app can have multiple producers

Comment: @cricket_007 Even multiple producers are not needed, one kafkaproducer object can produce to multiple topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must mix multiple message types in a single topic (to maintain chronological order of the messages, for example), then I'd suggest having a single overloaded message type which can represent each of your disparate message types and which is able to answer the kind of message it holds. Then set up a separate consumer group for each message type and associated processing logic. Finally, modify the logic in each consumer to only process appropriate messages.

Having two different consumer groups assumes that you have roughly the same number of messages of each type, otherwise there could be a lot of wasted CPU. If one message type occurs orders of magnitudes more often that the other, you might be better off merging the two consumers into a single consumer with a branch to perform the appropriate processing.

Widely differing numbers of messages can also interfere with processing the two types of messages chronologically with two different consumer groups.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to simply use [KafkaConsumer#assign()](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign(java.util.Collection)) and specify the proper partitions.

Alternatively if you are okay with twice the I/O, simply use two consumer groups - both consumers will get all the messages, and in your consumer logic you can simply skip the messages of unwanted type.