# How to specify the Kafka topic's partition in Kafka Connect Sink

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-partition

I am trying to specify a topic partition for my Kafka Connect Sink. In particular, I am using the [DataStax Apache Kafka Connector](https://www.datastax.com/dev/datastax-apache-kafka-connector).

There is a good amount of documentation and resources related to specifying a topic partition for a Kafka Consumer, for example:

- https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-console-consumer-read-specific-offsets-partitions/kafka.html
- [consumer.How to specify partition to read? [kafka]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492707/consumer-how-to-specify-partition-to-read-kafka)

However, I haven't been able to find anything at all regarding how to specify what partition a given Kafka Connect Sink Connector reads from.

It seems like the [Confluent connector developer docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/devguide.html#dynamic-input-output-partitions) imply that specifying partition should be possible, but I don't see any config that I can set in the generic [Kafka Sink Configuration Properties docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/connect/sink-connect-configs.html) nor in the [DSE Kafka Connector configuration docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaConfigTasksTOC.html).

My understanding is that a Kafka Connect Sink is basically a specific implementation of a Kafka Consumer that writes to a given data store. If so, it should be possible to specify a partition, is that correct? Or am I misunderstanding something about how Kafka Connectors work?

Comment: why do you need to fetch only specific partition?

Comment: @AlexOtt We're thinking of using a topic topology where we are consuming from a topic, enriching the data, then writing back to the same topic but to different partitions. Kafka Connect would then consume only the enriched data on those specific partitions. I think the idea would be that this topic could be scaled and managed as a single unit. 

We can probably get around this though by just using two separate topics

Comment: It’s not very scalable solution and it’s very easy to break something. Two topics is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify partitions in the Connect API. It subscribes to all partitions, then distributes consumer instances amongst worker tasks as part of a consumer group.